# How to generate unique id's, without knowing other id's?

Tags: java, algorithm, random

I'm implementing messages on an application (not realtime messages), and I have all the sending and receiving set up, but I'll make things a lot easier if I could generate unique id's for the messages before sending them to the server.

So because the id is generated before reaching the server, I can't know the other id's in order to make a new one. I could use a random string or something, of course the problem is that it's possible that sometime one of the id's repeats. But how do I make sure that that is very unlikely and it's not a gigantic string.

Comment: you can add user_id and chatroom_id and time in your generated uniq string..

Comment: you can use a GUID.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Comment: [Universally Unique Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)

Comment: Or ... just prefix your "locally" unique id strings with a different string; e.g. "S" for server and "C" for client.

Comment: The linked duplicate solves a version of your problem with additional constraints on the solution; e.g. no local persistence.  But the solutions are practical, and should also work for you.

Comment: Wow thanks I found want I wanted, and I see that my question is a duplicate, what do I do? do I delete the question?

Comment: You can delete it if you want.  Or just leave it.